# SeedLabs Cryto_PKI lab, failed to start docker compose (dcup)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, containers

I'm running of SEEDUbuntu
After I build the container, when I try to start it, it'll hang on attaching to www-10.9.0.80. What can I do to try and fix this?

```
Starting www-10.9.0.80 ... done
Attaching to www-10.9.0.80
```

contents of docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    web-server:
        build: ./image_www
        image: seed-image-www-pki
        container_name: www-10.9.0.80
        tty: true
        volumes:
            - ./volumes:/volumes

        networks:
            net-10.9.0.0:
                ipv4_address: 10.9.0.80

networks:
    net-10.9.0.0:
        name: net-10.9.0.0
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 10.9.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. If you want your command line back, you will have to run the docker command in detached mode.

```
docker-compose up -d
```